# Overriding a method with a getter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, overriding

The code below runs as intended however are they any **disadvantages** to override a method (see **action_label** in the code below) with the getter of an attribute? See the **:action_label** in the code

```
class BaseAction
  def action_label
    raise NotImplementedError
  end

  def run
    puts "Running action: #{action_label}"
    yield        
  end
end

class SimpleAction < BaseAction  

  def initialize(label)    
    @action_label = label
  end

  private
  attr_reader :action_label
end

sa = SimpleAction.new("foo")
sa.run {puts "action!"}
```

Comment: I am unsure why this was downvoted, so I upvoted it for the sake of entropy constancy. That’s completely fine, because `attr_reader` is nothing but a syntactic sugar for `def action_label; @action_label; end`.

Comment: Your example seems a little overcomplicated. You can get almost the exact same behavior by not messing around with any methods and just accessing `@action_label` directly and having a `raise foo unless @action_label` in the base class.

Comment: The example is maybe complicated because I am trying to mimic an `abstract` class available to other languages, where one is trying to enforce children classes to override a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_reader :action_label` is just defining a method. "getters" in Ruby are just methods like this

```
def action_label
  @action_label
end
```

`attr_reader` is shorthand for defining such a method.

There is nothing wrong with redefining a method in a subclass, that's one of the big features of OOP.

Also that is not what [NotImplementedError](http://chrisstump.online/2016/03/23/stop-abusing-notimplementederror/) is for. Raise something else.

Comment: Abstract classes are not really a thing in Ruby (since method definition and dispatch are both dynamic). I would just throw `NoMethodError`.